# CSS Fade between Background Color and Image

Tags: html, css

I made a simple CSS Grid with some Tiles, and at the moment, I'm trying to set the tiles so that when you hover over them a Background Appears, i tried the transition tag but it doesn't work. Tried a few Solutions from the Web but they didn't worked with the Grid System. I'm trying to add a little Delay before the Image Appears.

```css
.box1 {
  background: #6fc3df;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box1 h1 {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.box1:hover {
  background-image: url("images/pic02.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="box box1">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @patric see this https://jsfiddle.net/26L1b4jf/

Comment: i think your image path is wrong it is working i just change the image url or else if problem is something else please elaborate

Comment: thx already, i did the same with my code but i want a little delay on the change to the background, so it isnt instanly poping up

Comment: for that you can use setTimeout() in javascript or can use jquery

Comment: Im pretty new to this is it possible for you to provide some code?

Comment: so many answers you got  already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small hack.

Wrap the `div` which need to fade another div with intended background and make child's background transparent once mouse hover over it.

**Note:** OP wanted to do this with multiple `div`'s with different images. So here is an example with two `div`'s.

```css
#wrapper-1{
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100x50") rgba(111, 195, 223, 1);
}

#wrapper-2{
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x100") rgba(111, 195, 223, 1);
}

.box1, .box2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3 ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
    background: rgba(111, 195, 223, 1);
}

.box1 h1, .box2 h1{
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.box1:hover, .box2:hover{
  background: rgba(111, 195, 223, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
    <div id="wrapper-1">
      <div class="box box1">
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper-2">
      <div class="box box2">
          <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx alot it helped a lot only thing i changed is that the wrapper class is before the tiles lass because otherwise the tiles wouldn't be the right shape anymore. Is there a possible Solution how i can set a different Picture for every tile. Here is the complete code for better overview: https://jsfiddle.net/o20bud9h/

Comment: @SirFail just make separate wrapper `div` for all the `div`s where you want this. Although I would recommend changing `.wrapper` class to some id i.e.`#wrapper-one`

Comment: when i do that the tiles get all unformatted and dont have the right size anymore

Comment: @SirFail I have updated the code. It does same thing with two `div`.

Comment: i did it myself like this and the grid is now completly Broken, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/xbu7L0g5/

Comment: `.tiles` `height` property seems to be breaking it. Remove that and you should be fine https://jsfiddle.net/2v93cx0f/

Comment: yeh it fixes it slightly but normaly the grid should look like this: http://prntscr.com/peg4yo

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some things in your code. CSS transition doesn't work with background images, so i changed it to an image tag. See new code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqyufwLc/)

```
<div class="tiles">
<div class="box box1">
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <img src="https://www.mail-signatures.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/How-to-find-direct-link-to-image_Blog-Picture.png" />
</div>
<div class="box box2">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

```
.box1 {
    background: #6fc3df;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3 ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.box1 h1 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

img {
  transition: 1s opacity;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box1:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this suit your needs?

```css
div {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 280px;
  width: 480px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "1";
  color: white;
  font-size: 144px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

div::before,
div::after {
  position: absolute;
}

div::after {
top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(http://connexo.de/img/screenshots/lbbw-falcon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```